# Could we replace pump in Rankine cycle with just a check valve?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Is it possible for a rankine cycle to work without a feed pump?
Or if we replace the feed by the check valve?
Or maybe if we use gravity only?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the Rankine power cycle. The pump is needed to take the saturated liquid that leaves the condenser at low pressure and feed it to the boiler at high pressure. Neither a check valve nor gravity can do that.

Hope this helps.